# Estou tentando entender esses códigos, mas não está fazendo sentido para mim. Alguém pode me ajudar? Sou iniciante

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, bottle

A ideia é que o código Javascript se comunique com o código Python chamando uma função e fornecendo argumentos, mas exatamente como isso funciona não entendi muito bem.

Código javascript:

```
set_wheels (args)
    {
        const dist = Cast.toString(args.DISTANCE);
        $.ajax({
          header: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
          },
          url: 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080'+'/set_wheels?lw='+dist,
          success: function( response ) {
              log.log(response);
              log.log(dist);
          }
        });
    }
```

Código python:

```
from bottle import Bottle,response,request

class Classe(Bottle):
    def set_wheels(self):
            response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
            response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
            response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token'
            response.headers["Set-Cookie"]= 'SameSite=None;Secure'
            rw=request.GET.get('rw', '').strip()
            lw=request.GET.get('lw', '').strip()
            self.rapi.setJointSpeed(right_rotation=float(rw),left_rotation=float(lw))
        #     print("set_wheels")
            return "set_wheels"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite,

Tive dificuldade parecida quando comecei a programar em Java Script.

Não programo muito em Python para este fim no qual esta usando. Mais posso ajudar a entender um pouco.

O Ajax é responsável por fazer uma comunicação via POST ou GET com o *backend*, e passar dados para o mesmo. Sendo assim sempre que o Ajax é executado ele "chama" a pagina através do URL e troca dados observe que há a função *success*, que é onde há o retorno caso a pagina esteja disponível e a comunicação tenha dado certo. Pode ser usado ainda *beforeSend* e *error*. *BeforeSend* é executado enquanto estiver executando a solicitação Ajax. E caso dê algo de errado ao invés de executar o *success* ira executar *error*. Veja abaixo.

```js
        const dist = Cast.toString(args.DISTANCE); 
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          header: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
          },
          url: "http://url_requisicao",
          data: {"variavel":valor, "variavel2":valor2},
          beforeSend: function () {
            //faça algo aqui enquanto carrega.
        }, 
          success: function( response ) {
              log.log(response);
              log.log(dist);
          },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Erro. Falha na conexão!");
        }
          
        });
```

Observe ainda que consigo passar dados específicos através do método "data:". E ainda escolher o método POST ou GET.

Na documentação do [site](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) oficial contem mais detalhes.

Na pagina em Python que você ira apontar através da variável "url" no Ajax, pode ser executado o que quiser. E receber os valores enviados via Ajax. Veja:

```
import cgi;
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

if (form.has_key("variavel") and form.has_key("variavel2")):
    display_data(form["variavel"].value, form["variavel2"].value)
else:
    display_error()
```

Seria mais ou menos isso ai caso queira executar uma função especifica seria interessante receber o valor do Ajax em uma variável e criar uma condição para chamar esta função.

Fonte: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ;
https://gist.github.com/twmht/9935260 ;
https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html ;

Comment: Legaal! Interessante, obrigado pela resposta! Só não entendi muito bem essa parte de "de onde pra onde". Então a porta de comunicação é feita pela url? Ou seja, os dois vão ficar escutando essa url pra captar dados e assim, mandar um para o outro? Pelo o que entendi do seu codigo é:
vai ser do tipo post, ou seja, vai MANDAR dados; os headers nao entendi pra que serve; url é de onde os dados serão mandados; data é os dados em si que serão mandados; sucess é se caso for mandado; esse log.log nao entedi tbm, vc sabe oq é?

Comment: Isso mesmo, a porta é colocada na url, por ex: "http://minhapagina:8080";

Comment: headers: como já diz é um cabeçalho, e passa informações para a pagina de requisição. não necessariamente precisa incluir na solicitação Ajax, a não ser que seja um caso que necessite que seja passado. Se for observar todas as paginas que acessa possui cabeçalho com algumas informações. Basta olhar indo na parte de desenvolvedor do navegador. log.log() pode ser substituído por console.log(resposta). Ele vai mostrar a resposta de retorno da função Ajax, mais isso é só para ver a informação na parte de desenvolver, não precisa mostras isso. Use somente ajudar tratar o código de retorno do Ajax.

Comment: Hmmm, acho que está ficando mais claro mesmo. O essencial então é o type, data e url então ne? Aí nesse código em Python que vc fez, a forma com que ele vai RECEBER os dados seria por meio desse form? No arquivo python nao usa nennhuma url? como ele vai saber de onde vem os dados?

Comment: Seria isso mesmo. Para saber a origem do endereço de requisição na pagina é só usar o seguinte código: 
import os
origin = os.environ.get("REMOTE_HOST")